# tinymce - how to save rich text and plain text versions at the same time

Tags: tinymce, rte

I would like to leave user to make rich text with tinymce and save it in db, but also I want to save plain text version.

Does tinymce provide such option?

Answer (score 2):

No, tinymce is designed to create HTML/rich text. But you are free to grad the plain text content of a tinymce editor and save it yourself.

There you go:

```
var plain_text = $(ed.getBody()).text();
```

Comment: Great. So could we possibly take this further? I'd like to get the text content, but preserving "line breaks" - meaning I want every `<br>`, `<p>`, and other block level elements to translate appropriately to a new line. This content should then be able to sit in a `<textarea>` according to those line breaks.

Answer (score 1):

You can get plain text using this code:

```
var plainText = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getBody().textContent;
```

ALso you can get html text using this one:

```
var richText = tinyMCE.getInstanceById('textAreaID').getContent();
```

Comment: Great. So could we possibly take this further? I'd like to get the text content, but preserving "line breaks" - meaning I want every `<br>`, `<p>`, and other block level elements to translate appropriately to a new line. This content should then be able to sit in a `<textarea>` according to those line breaks.